# Why do issue view page requires an extra refresh to see the customfield value?

Tags: jira, custom-fields, jira-plugin, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I am updating my custom field pro-grammatically if custom field is left blank. I found a question on stack related to this which helped in saving/updating custom field value correctly.I referred [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8251892/how-do-i-save-a-value-into-a-custom-field-in-jira-programmatically) .

As I said I am updating custom field if it is left blank. So I have written some java  code which checks if custom field is null if yes then I am generating some values using java code and updating and saving value in database. This all is working fine. I am doing this all when create issue.

But when issue page is rendered the respective custom field is not displayed,it need an extra page refresh for that. After page reload the custom field is rendered on page with correct value.

Any ideas? Why page reload is required ? 
Can some point me to write direction ?
I am using JIRA 6.0.x

I am writing code in **MyCustomField extends AbstractSingleFieldType** class and using its **getVelocityParameters** method

Answer (score 0):

Check your log files for errors seen the first time the screen is loaded? May also be errors shown in the JavaScript console? Otherwise strip everything back to be as simple as possible and then add complexity back in until it breaks in the same way.

Comment: Checked for log files,but there are no errors.Also there are no error in JavaScript console.

Comment: I fetching data from servlet and then displaying it for custom filed on view issue page. But for this I need an extra page reload !!